# Mongoose access from angular controller

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I try to do a simple server/client in node/angular connected with mongoose to a MongoDB database.

my structure :

```
app/
   app.js   (mongoose connect / schema /models )
   bower.json
   components/
      app.module.js
      app.routes.js
      artistes/
        addArtist.html
        addArtistController.js
      home/ (html controller service)
   shared/ (header & footer html)
   assets/  (css/js/img/fonts)
   bower_components/  
   index.html (main index)
data/    (mongo db)
mongod*        (script to launch mongodo)
package.json   (npm start)
routes/
bin/  
models/  (empty)
node_modules/     
server.js
```

I want to group all the mongoose logic in the server.js then when it will work I'll put the model in a model directory, but not now.

My server got the mongoose connect, schema and model creation
a save function and a find function.
But i m totally lost for this :

- How in my addArtistController can I access my save and find function from server.js?  I can't require('mongoose') as require is not made for browser side. Any example would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a *request* to your server, with the help for example of Angularjs `$http`.

I can't really tell how to do this from server side as you do not share your server.js, but assuming you already have an endpoint for your `find` function which is returning your MongoDB data (I suggest to use express Router for that), in frontend (controller, service, etc.) you can try something like this:

```
// Angular v1
angular.module('addArtistController')
  .controller('AddArtist', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("/find").then(function (data) {
          $scope.data = data; // data is now available in the scope
      }, function (err) {
          console.log(err)
      });
  }])
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

I'm still new to latest version of Angular but the concept remains the same.

```
// Angular v4
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get('/find')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      resolve(this.data);
    });
});
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Http-class.html